# Resize font size to be fixed into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fix a text into the div, It is working if the text is increased, but when user presses backspace, it should get back to its size and fit into the div

```js
$(".engravingText").keyup(function() {
  $('#overlay_image_text').html($('.engravingText').val());
  var el = document.querySelector('#overlay_image_text');
  var orgFontSize = getStyle(el, 'font-size');



  var tst = document.createElement('span');
  tst.textContent = el.textContent;
  tst.style = 'position:absolute;left:-9999px;display:inline-block;';
  document.body.appendChild(tst);

  tst.style.fontSize = orgFontSize;
  tst.style.fontWeight = getStyle(el, 'font-weight');
  tst.style.fontFamily = getStyle(el, 'font-family').split(',')[0];
  var i = parseInt(tst.style.fontSize);

  for (; i > 0; i--) {
    if (parseInt(getStyle(tst, 'width')) < 200) {

      el.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
      break;
    }
    tst.style.fontSize = i + 'px';

  }
  document.body.removeChild(tst);
});

function getStyle(elem, prop) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
}
```

```css
#overlay_image_text {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px !important;
  margin-left: 35px !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay_image_text">HHHHH</div>
<br />
<input type="text" maxlength="20" style="font-family: Cherokee; background-color: transparent; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;" class="form-control engravingText" placeholder="Please type engraving text here" value="">
```

Comment: orgFontSize shouldn't be inside the keyup handler. It is reset on each keyup and the font size can't grow once it's shrunk.

Comment: tried that, it doesn't help in that case either

Comment: See my answer below. I think it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your snippet fixed. As per my comment orgFontSize shouldn't be inside the keyup handler. It is reset on each keyup and the font size can't grow once it's shrunk.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#overlay_image_text');
var orgFontSize = getStyle(el, 'font-size');

$(".engravingText").keyup(function() {
  $('#overlay_image_text').html($('.engravingText').val());

  var tst = document.createElement('span');
  tst.textContent = el.textContent;
  tst.style = 'position:absolute;left:-9999px;display:inline-block;';
  document.body.appendChild(tst);

  tst.style.fontSize = orgFontSize;
  tst.style.fontWeight = getStyle(el, 'font-weight');
  tst.style.fontFamily = getStyle(el, 'font-family').split(',')[0];
  var i = parseInt(tst.style.fontSize);

  for (; i > 0; i--) {
    if (parseInt(getStyle(tst, 'width')) < 200) {

      el.style.fontSize = i + 'px';
      break;
    }
    tst.style.fontSize = i + 'px';

  }
  document.body.removeChild(tst);
});

function getStyle(elem, prop) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
}
```

```css
#overlay_image_text {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px !important;
  margin-left: 35px !important;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #aeaeae;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay_image_text">HHHHH</div>
<br />
<input type="text" maxlength="20" style="font-family: Cherokee; background-color: transparent; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;" class="form-control engravingText" placeholder="Please type engraving text here" value="">
```

Comment: Can you please edit the answer with making the text vertically in middle?